# Why can't Hibernate see newly created data?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Im creating a simple web app using Spring and Hibernate that has something to do with online shopping. My program is doing well when inserting new data using hibernate. When I check the db, the data is there. The problem is, the moment I fetch the new data I created, it gets nothing. I tried to put data in the db manually and hibernate gets the data. I'm sorry if this seems a beginner question, I'm studying Hibernate as a part of my training as a jr web developer. First, I wanna show you the config:

```
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/------" />
    <property name="username" value="----" />
    <property name="password" value="------" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource" />
    </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.qbryx.domain" />
</bean>
```

Here is the code for adding a new product:

```
@Override
public void addProduct(Product product) {

    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

    Transaction transaction = null;

    try {
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        Query query = session.createSQLQuery(DAOQuery.HQL_ADD_PRODUCT).setParameter("upc", product.getUpc())
                             .setParameter("category", product.getCategory().getCategoryId())
                             .setParameter("name", product.getName()).setParameter("description", product.getDescription())
                             .setParameter("price", product.getPrice());

        query.executeUpdate();

        transaction.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (transaction != null)
            transaction.rollback();

        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

        session.close();
    }
}

@Override
public void addProductStock(InventoryProduct inventoryProduct) {

    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

    Transaction transaction = null;

    try {
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();

        Query query = session.createSQLQuery(DAOQuery.HQL_ADD_PRODUCT_STOCK)
                             .setParameter("upc", inventoryProduct.getUpc())
                             .setParameter("stock", inventoryProduct.getStock());

        query.executeUpdate();

        transaction.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

        session.close();
    }

}
```

This code does fine with adding a new product together with the stock. Here is my code for fetching the product:

```
@Override
public InventoryProduct getInventoryProductByUpc(String upc) {

    InventoryProduct product = null;

    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

    Transaction transaction = null;

    try {
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();

        Query query = session.createQuery(DAOQuery.HQL_GET_INVENTORY_PRODUCT)
                             .setParameter("upc", upc);

        product = (InventoryProduct) query.getSingleResult();

        transaction.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (transaction != null)
            transaction.rollback();

        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }

    return product;
}
```

I don't understand why Hibernate can fetch data that is manually added to the database but not the data added through Hibernate. I need help. Thanks!

Comment: Firstly why are you using a query to insert the object when you can do session.save(product); http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#save(java.lang.Object). This not only kind of defeats the purpose of using an ORM in the first place but can lead to side effects. See https://docs.oracle.com/html/E24396_01/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_bulk_ops. So refactor to use the save method and take it from there.